# How to stop ispell-message in notmuch-message-mode from checking quotes and citations?

Tags: notmuch, message-mode

Per the documentation `` (`ispell-message) `` should ignore text from quoted mails.

For example:

"My interlocuter" email@domain.net writes:

> mispeled

But for some reason my emacs asks me to correct 'mispeled' above in this very message!

I'm using emacs 28.2 on Debian bookworm with notmuch. I think the issue is related to Message[Notmuch] mode. It works as expected in plain Message mode.

Thanks for the help!